# Write a JObject from a JArray using the object's Key-Pair values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have  a  `JArray`  which  looks  as  follows:

```
[
 {
    "key": "S8710 Server",
    "value": "M"
 },
 {
    "key": "Java",
    "value": "M"
 }
]
```

This  `JArray` needs to  be converted  into  a `JObject`  by  taking the key and  value such that  the  output object  looks like  this:

```
{
   "S8710 Server": "M",
   "Java": "M"
}
```

Is  this  conversion  Possible?  Any help would  be  greatly appreciated.
What  I tried  is  extracting the  keys and  values  from  a `DataTable`  and serializing  the  result of that.  Then  I  tried `JObject.Parse`.

```
var skillList = from skill in ds.Tables[4].AsEnumerable()
                where skill.Field<Int64>("ResumeID") == applicantValue.ResumeID
                select new clsResume.ExtractRatingInfo
                {
                     key = skill.Field<string>("Skill"),
                     value = skill.Field<string>("SkillRating")
                };

string skillResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(skillList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(skillResult);
```

Comment: @bit I tried  to  serailize  a  datatable  which contains  the  Keys and values  . And tried JObject.Parse

Comment: yes this is very much possible but would you please show us what have you tried till now. Some piece of code would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can transform your JSON like this:

```
JObject result = new JObject(
    jArray.Select(jt => new JProperty((string)jt["key"], jt["value"]))
);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CcLj3D

Note: the keys must be distinct across all objects in the array for this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Create JToken by passing the content string into JArray`s static method Parse.
get the inner childs from JToken and then look for the properties and their values.

like this:

```
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(YOUR_CONTENT_GOES_HERE);
        foreach (var token in jArray.Children<JToken>())
        {
            var firstProp = token.Children<JProperty>().First(param => param.Name == "S8710 Server");
            var firstValue = firstProp.Value<string>();

            var secondProp = token.Children<JProperty>().First(param => param.Name == "Java");
            var secondValue = firstProp.Value<string>();

        }
```